# Stop gnome from asking root password?

Tags: gnome, root

I'm on **the wheel group**.

I've uncommented:

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Yet every single time i log into gnome and try to do anything that requires root privilegies i'm asked for the password. Is there any way to stop this?

**Distribution CentOS 6.8.**

Thanks!

Comment: You mean, when you do `sudo COMMAND` you are being prompted, where COMMAND is some command that requires root privileges? Or are you saying that you select a menu option that would require root privileges (such as modifying the firewall) and you are prompted?

Comment: On what distribution?

Comment: @Gilles Centos 6.8.

Comment: @KevinO The second one, right after login i'm greeted with "authentication is required to set the network proxy used for downloading packages". But i don't want to only get rid of this particular message, i just don't want to be asked for root password when changing settings that would require root privileges. I'm already on wheel and a sudoer. What else can i try?